# CURLOPT_STDERR is always executed?

Tags: php, curl, stderr, verbosity

Well, I'm having troubles making requests to the Discord API, I'm not understanding how curl is working.

This is my code:

```php
function make_request($mixed, $token, $get_json = true) {
    $url = is_string($mixed) ? $mixed : getApiUrl($mixed);
    // TODO: Check for valid url!

    $log_file = __DIR__.'/../logs/request.txt';
    if(!is_readable($log_file)) printError("File '$log_file' is not readable!");
    if(!is_writable($log_file)) printError("File '$log_file' is not writable!");

    $ch = curl_init();
    $f = fopen($log_file, 'w+');

    if($f === false) printError("There was an error opening '$log_file'!");
    ftruncate($f, 0);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url, 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: Bot ' . $token), 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_STDERR         => $f,
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    fclose($f);
    curl_close($ch);

    $contents = file_get_contents($log_file);
    if($contents != '') 
    {
        // Censor bot key!
        $contents = preg_replace("/^Authorization: Bot.+?$/", "Authorization: Bot xxx", $contents);
        printError($contents);
    }

    if($get_json) {
        $pretty = isset($_GET["pretty"]);

        if($pretty) {
            $json = json_decode($response);
            return json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    return json_decode($response, true);
}
```

And this is my output:

```
[OuterException] System.Exception: * Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 162.159.135.233...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to discordapp.com (162.159.135.233) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=ssl711320.cloudflaressl.com
*  start date: Feb 13 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 21 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "discordapp.com" matched cert's "discordapp.com"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/guilds/479096180601782274 HTTP/1.1
Host: discordapp.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bot ...

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 17:49:15 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=ddfc25d7448507e06474f24ff3e8352381582220955; expires=Sat, 21-Mar-20 17:49:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< Via: 1.1 google
< Alt-Svc: clear
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Set-Cookie: __cfruid=66721d8d16cd42e4884dc62afe94705cbf1e21df-1582220955; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 568250ea9fe2a861-CDG
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host discordapp.com left intact

   en DiscordIdCrawler.Lib.Core.ApiWorker.CheckForErrors(Object response) en E:\PHP\discord-flooder-bot\client\DiscordIdCrawler\DiscordIdCrawler.Lib\Core\ApiWorker.cs:línea 152
   en DiscordIdCrawler.Lib.Core.ApiWorker.GetServerName(Int64 serverId) en E:\PHP\discord-flooder-bot\client\DiscordIdCrawler\DiscordIdCrawler.Lib\Core\ApiWorker.cs:línea 312
   en DiscordIdCrawler.Lib.Core.DriverWorker.GoToServer(IWebDriver web, Int32 serverNum, Boolean storeOnDB) en E:\PHP\discord-flooder-bot\client\DiscordIdCrawler\DiscordIdCrawler.Lib\Core\DriverWorker.cs:línea 141
```

My question is that maybe I'm printing an error when curl is just showing a verbosed log, but I'm not sure if the `CURLOPT_STDERR` is used to print errors or the entire log.

On the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> An alternative location to output errors to instead of STDERR.

Maybe is because `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` is enabled.

> TRUE to output verbose information. Writes output to STDERR, or the file specified using CURLOPT_STDERR.

On that case, I need to know when an error happens. Any tip here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you want the diagnostic output, you have to arrange to capture it *before* you make your request. The usual way to do this is by storing it in RAM, checking for curl error, and handling appropriately.

That code looks like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    // ... other options here
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => ($log = fopen('php://temp', 'w')),
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (false === $response) {
    $errno = curl_error($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_strerror($errno);
    $logtext = stream_get_contents($log, -1, 0);
    // ... log the info above, take action, etc.
} else {
    // ... $response is your HTTP response
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know how to store it on RAM in php, normally in C# we use Streams. And yes, the problem was that I was not using curl_error. ^^'